# es6 get access to class constructor from static function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am trying to create a static function that generated a new instance. The instance is of the class the static function belongs to.

Here's an example

```
class A {
  static getInstance() {
    return new A();
  }
}
```

So far so good `let a = A.getInstance();` will work fine.

I want to inherit this functionality in children classes.

```
class B extends A {}
let b = B.getInstance(); // This will return an instance of A.
```

I want `B.getInstance()` to return an instance of B.

Comment: `static getInstance() { return new this; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work..  I assume you want this as you want to pass a class as some sort of constructor / generator.  As doing `new A()` is obviously a bit simpler.

```js
class A {
  sayIt() { console.log('I am A'); }
  static getInstance() {
    return new this;
  }
}

class B extends A { sayIt() { console.log('I am B') } }

var k = A.getInstance();
k.sayIt();

let b = B.getInstance(); 
b.sayIt();

let k2 = new A();
k2.sayIt();

let b2 = new B();
b2.sayIt();
```

Comment: Thanks Keith for the attention. It does work. To build on your answer, if you change sayIt() to static as well, you can replace 'I am B' with `I am ${this.name}` and it'll print the class it belongs to :) Which is exactly solve my problem. Thanks again.